# How to prevent finder favorites from disappearing when a remote drive disconnects?

Tags: macos, finder

I'm using pCloud Drive (3.11.4) on Mac OS Monterey (12.2 (21D49)). I like to have my favorite folders in the sidebar in Finder. However, sometimes when pCloud disconnects, the favorites disappear. Restarting pCloud Drive does not restore the favorites.

Is there any way to permanently keep finder favorites in the sidebar?